# Boto 3 hanging in Lambda

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, boto3

I'm attempting to use Lambda to take snapshots of Elasticsearch clusters. My script works perfectly locally, but in Lambda it hangs while trying to scan DynamoDB (My source of truth for the Elasticsearch locations) In order to rule out IAM permissions I gave the function full admin as a temporary measure for debugging. My code is below:

```
import boto3
import datetime
import json
import requests

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='us-east-1')

# change this to whatever your table name is
table = dynamodb.Table('elasticsearch-backups')
today = datetime.date.today()

# I don't fully understand the reason for this. Following example
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Python.04.html
pe = "#dmn, #pth, #bkt"
ean = {"#dmn": "domain", "#pth": "path", "#bkt": "bucket"}


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print "started"

    print "scanning table"


# hangs at this table.scan call


    nodes = table.scan(
        ProjectionExpression=pe,
        ExpressionAttributeNames=ean
        )

    print "nodes are " + str(nodes)

    for i in nodes['Items']:
        bucket = str(i['bucket'])
        path = str(i['path'])

        print "bucket is " + str(i['bucket'])
        print "base_path is " + str(i['path'])

        print "setting repository json"
        repository = {
            "type": "s3",
            "settings": {
                "bucket": bucket,
                "base_path": path
            }
        }
        print "repository json is " + json.dumps(repository)

        print "setting url path"
        url = i['domain'] + "/_snapshot/lambda_s3_repository"
        print "url path is " + url

    # create repository
        print "creating repository"
        response = requests.put(
            url,
            data=json.dumps(repository)
            )
        print response.content

    # start snapshot
        print "starting snapshot"
        url = url + "/" + str(today)
        response = requests.put(
            url
            )
        print response.content

lambda_handler("test", "test")
```

Is there anything that I can do to get greater visibility into what's happening in that hanging function call to debug further? I'm seeing literally nothing in the logs. It doesn't fail, it just hangs until Lambda kills it.

Comment: Hanging at that step sounds like a network connectivity issue. If it was a permissions issue you would get an error back immediately. Did you by chance happen to enable VPC access for your Lambda function?

Comment: Yes, that's almost certainly it. I didn't enable the NAT gateway. I'll do that and report back

Comment: Unfortunately a NAT instance already exists in that subnet, with routes set up correctly. It's not the managed NAT, but that shouldn't matter AFAIK

Comment: Like an idiot, I had been overly restrictive in my outgoing security group. Thanks for pointing me in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I was not able to connect out to the DynamoDB API. This can be caused by not setting up a NAT on a VPC function as suggested by Mark B, but in this case I had been overly restrictive with outgoing security groups.